# How do I install the PowerShell Community Extensions (PSCX)

Tags: windows, windows-8, powershell

I'm on Windows 8.1, and fairly new to Windows-side development. I've had PSCX suggested to me, but for the life of me, I can't figure out how to install PSCX 3.1 on Windows 8.1 and make the cmdlets work when I type them. (To put it frankly.)

I've downloaded and run the `.msi` for 3.1 from the website; as far as I can tell, it ran successfully and exited. However, running, for instance, `Expand-Archive`, fails.

`Get-Module -ListAvailable` doesn't show anything about PSCX. I checked my `WindowsPowerShell` directory (in `C:\Users\ELLIOTTCABLE\Documents\WindowsPowerShell`), there's no `Modules` directory in there. Just my `PS1` profile.

Where, if anywhere, has the `.msi` installed this; and how do I get PowerShell to recognize it? (My setup is very generic, nothing strange going on on my end afaict. Again, new to Windows.)

Answer (score 2):

After upgrading to Windows 8.1 from 7 (via 8.0) I found the same issue.

However it turns out Pscx is installed here: `C:\Program Files (x86)\PowerShell Community Extensions\Pscx3\Pscx\` (in my case as I've got Pscx 3.1 installed now).

And there's a `PSModulePath` environment variable that points to `C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\`

The environment variable just needs to be updated to add the path to Pscx. I guess either something reset the path on upgrade or moved Pscx out of the system32 location.

See also https://pscx.codeplex.com/workitem/34912

Answer (score 1):

I also had experienced this issue after installing the latest 3.2 version. However, I was able to get over the issue by following these steps:

1. copy the "Pscx" folder located in "C:\Program Files (x86)\PowerShell Community Extensions\Pscx3".
2. Paste this folder in the $PSHome location (usually it is: "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules").
3. Run Import-Module Pscx
4. You are done! Just run an example command to verify if its working (e.g. [hex] 5123123).

Answer (score 0):

PSCX is available as a zip and all you have to do is copy the contents of the zip file to your modules folder `$PSHome\Modules`.  You can then import it for use using `import-module pscx`

To find out where these paths are, you can use `Write-Host $PSHome`

Comment: That works for older versions; but the current version is an `.msi` ... and it doesn't seem to do *anything*. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: All I can recommend is you searh your pc for *.psd1 and take a copy of it to your modules folder ready for import.  I've just downloaded and installed the latest version (was running 2.1 before) and it seemed t work ok